# Can't boot into Windows 8 PE

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-8

I'm running Ubuntu 17.10 on my Dell Latitude E6410 and I'm new to Linux. I needed to boot into Windows to check a battery issue so I searched for a Windows live CD and I found this windows 8 PE (Gandalf's_Win8PE_x86) and I burned it to a USB stick using [this method](https://onetransistor.blogspot.com.eg/2014/09/make-bootable-windows-usb-from-ubuntu.html).

The problem is, when I try to boot into Win8 PE from the USB, I get into the GRUB command line instead of the GUI.

Is there something I can type in there that will boot Windows PE? Or is there a way to switch back to the GUI GRUB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After a lot of searching and tries, I finally came up with a solution!

This is how to burn Gandalf's Windows PE ISO(s) Using Ubuntu.

1. Prepare USB using GParted:

   msdos  -  fat32 / ntfs  - check ( boot ) in Partition flag
2. Install ISO using Unetbootin.
3. Make it bootable

   ```
   sudo grub-install --target=i386-pc --boot-directory="/media/<username>/<drive_label>/boot" /dev/sdX
   ```

   **Replace:**

   `/media/<username>/<drive_label>` with the path where USB drive is mounted, `/dev/sdX` with the USB drive, not the partition (e.g. `/dev/sdb` not `/dev/sdb1`)
4. Create a file named `grub.cfg` in the USB drive in `/boot/grub` folder:

   Add the following text to the `grub.cfg` file :-

   ```
   default=1  
   timeout=15
   color_normal=light-cyan/dark-gray
   menu_color_normal=black/light-cyan
   menu_color_highlight=white/black

   menuentry "Start Windows Installation" {
       insmod ntfs
       insmod search_label
       search --no-floppy --set=root --label <USB_drive_label> --hint hd0,msdos1
       ntldr /bootmgr
       boot
   }

   menuentry "Boot from the first hard drive" {
       insmod ntfs
       insmod chain
       insmod part_msdos
       insmod part_gpt
       set root=(hd1)
       chainloader +1
       boot
   }
   ```

And that's it!

Boot from the USB in legacy boot and you will boot from Windows in live mode without needing to install it.